# Where is the gwt server in production mode?

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt

I am learning GWT with the guide here, http://www.gwtproject.org/gettingstarted.html

I execute:

```
ant build
```

and see all files generated in the war/ folder.

However, that's all static and frontend things.

I open the generated HTML file only to find that the ajax requests failed because there is no server serving that.

I tried putting the war/ folder in tomcat's path, and open the HTML through tomcat server, it doesn't work, either.

So where is the server side program generated by gwt and how to use them?

Comment: doesn't GWT use jetty as it's default server?

Answer (score 2):

In production mode, only JavaScript and associated files are generated - you can use any server you want. For production, you almost certainly want more control over the server than what DevMode would provide with its built-in server (in fact, I would suggest that most teams shouldn't use the built-in server in *dev mode* either, except for the simplest of "Hello World" apps).

For something simple to get going and very similar to what DevMode can provide by default, check out Jetty or Tomcat, but there are many other great options as well, depending on what features you'd like to have.